# I am using this in python but cant able to know whats wrong

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

```
from datetime import datetime 
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']) 
for i in data:
    i['year']=i.Date.dt.year 
    i['month']=i.Date.dt.month 
    i['day']=i.Date.dt.day
```

error: 'str' object has no attribute 'Date'

Comment: What is `data`? How is it initialized? What does `data.columns` show?

Comment: What is `data` specifically? Looks like that is a string, rather than a `Dict`, based on the way you are using it.

Comment: assuming `data` is a `pandas` DataFrame: don't iterate over it. write e.g. `data['year'] = data['Date'].dt.year`.